# gzip Cannot enable in Wildfly 8?

Tags: gzip, wildfly

I want to enable gzip compression in wildfly server. I used the following tutorial. [Tutorial](http://rumianom.pl/rumianom/entry/gzip_content_encoding_in_wildfly#comment-1400152138000)

This is the gzip enabling code I included in the standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.0">
   <buffer-caches>
      <buffer-cache name="default" buffer-size="1024" buffers-per-region="1024" max-regions="10"/>
   </buffer-caches>
   <server name="default-server">
      <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
      <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
          <location name="/" handler="welcome-content" />
          **<filter-ref name="gzipFilter" predicate="path-suffix['.css'] or path-suffix['.js']" />**
          <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
          <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
      </host>
   </server>
   <servlet-container name="default" default-buffer-cache="default" stack-trace-on-error="local-only">
      <jsp-config/>
   </servlet-container>
   <handlers>
      <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content" directory-listing="true"/>
   </handlers>
   <filters>
      <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="Wildfly 8"/>
      <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow 1"/>
      <gzip name="gzipFilter"/>
   </filters>
</subsystem>
```

But When I used this code in the Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, It works perfectly. But when I installed the application in CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406. It doesn't work. I used the same settings. But I could not figure out the problem so far. I'm very grateful someone can provide your valuable idea.

Comment: can you provide also the wildfly version?

Comment: version is Wildfly 8.0

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to test upgrade to wildfly 8.2
I has the new undertow 1.1.0 interated which has solved a couple of issues around filters.

I assume your issue is also this:
[UNDERTOW-331](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-331)

Comment: I cannot Upgrade the system to wildfly 8.2. Because there are lot of dependencies in the system.

Comment: wildfly 8.0 and wildfly 8.2 are all  the same basis. Try a local upgrade and see if it is running. So you can easily check if the wildfly is the issue or the OS

Comment: Actually gzip is working. But it is not correctly zip the javascripts. It will provide errors when the page loading.

Comment: Actually gzip is working. But it is not correctly zip the javascripts. It will provide errors when the page loading. In some JavaScript files content are missing as an example : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined for jquery. In the other servers this error will not be produced.

Comment: Sorry, do not get fully your sentences. Is it working on wildfly 8.2 but not under wildfly 8?

Comment: In the browser I can see that gzip is enabled and working under 8.(I have different dependencies so I cannot check it 8.2). some Code snippets are missing in the gziped file.